# How many tri-state buffers can be connected in parallel?

Tags: parallel, buffer

According the 74HC244's datasheet, the maximum three–State Leakage Current IOZ, ( with Output in High–Impedance State, Vin = VIL or VIH, Vout = VCC or GND) is about 5 microamps. I want to connect N (about 20) of such integrated circuits with parallel outputs to the data bus in a reader selection scheme of only one of them (one is selected for reading, and the others are in Z-state). I wonder if the total output current in the Z state of the N-1 circuits not selected for reading can affect the logical value of the digital information read from the selected circuit. What is the maximum number of such circuits that can be connected in parallel?

Comment: Don’t shout - what did we do to you?

Comment: Consider capacitive loading too, the datasheet says each input is a 3.5pF load, adding 20 of them means whatever drives the data bus will have a 20x3.5pf=70pf load. This will affect the rise and fall times of data propagating through the driver into the 244's, so take that into account.

Comment: Please edit your question title to remove the shouting. It will get you attention but not the sort you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Quick est.
5uA x 20=0.1 mA so with HC244 driver at 50 ohms using Vol/Iol max results in 5mV loading.

3.5pF x 20 * 50 ohm = 3.5 ns slew rate load

Comment: Thank @Tony Stewart. Are there a maximum number of such circuits that can be connected in parallel?

Comment: 5V/5uA * 3.5pF= RC (input)=T= 3.5us for each load in tristate and 3.5ns for each load in active state might imply 1000 devices cuts   rise time to 3.5us so it depends on bus speed. You can check my math and add stray trace capacitance.